# ERROR: Supplied String module notation 'androidx.cardview.widget.CardView' is invalid

Tags: android, gradle, android-cardview, androidx

Here is my build gradle files

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview.widget.CardView'
```

Comment: post you module `build.gradle` and project `build.gradle`

Comment: Share your build.gradle files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview.widget.CardView'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

The `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` is the name of the class to be used in the code and in the layout. `androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0` is the name of the library which contains the `CardView` component.